# Regression with a small dataset

Tags: python, regression, non-linear-regression

We examined a software which was supposedly used for cracking. We discovered that the working time depends significantly on input length N, especially when N is greater than 10-15.
During our tests, we fixed the following working times.

```
N = 2 - 16.38 seconds 
N = 5 - 16.38 seconds 
N = 10 - 16.44 seconds 
N = 15 - 18.39 seconds 
N = 20 - 64.22 seconds 
N = 30 - 65774.62 seconds
```

Tasks: 
of Find the program working times for the following three cases -
 N = 25, N = 40 and N = 50.

I tried to do polynomial regression but the predictions varied from degree 2,3, ...

```
# Importing the libraries 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

# Importing the dataset 
X = np.array([[2],[5],[10],[15],[20],[30]])
X_predict = np.array([[25], [40], [50]])
y = np.array([[16.38],[16.38],[16.44],[18.39],[64.22],[65774.62]])
#y = np.array([[16.38/60],[16.38/60],[16.44/60],[18.39/60],[64.22/60],[65774.62/60]])


# Fitting Polynomial Regression to the dataset 
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures 

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 11) 
X_poly = poly.fit_transform(X) 

poly.fit(X_poly, y) 
lin2 = LinearRegression() 
lin2.fit(X_poly, y) 

# Visualising the Polynomial Regression results 
plt.scatter(X, y, color = 'blue') 

plt.plot(X, lin2.predict(poly.fit_transform(X)), color = 'red') 
plt.title('Polynomial Regression') 


plt.show() 

# Predicting a new result with Polynomial Regression 
lin2.predict(poly.fit_transform(X_predict))
```

For degree 2 the results were

```
array([[ 32067.76147835],
       [150765.87808383],
       [274174.84800471]])
```

For degree 5 the results were

```
array([[  10934.83739791],
       [ 621503.86217946],
       [2821409.3915933 ]])
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: what regression model should I use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After equation search I was able to fit the data to the equation "seconds = a * exp(b * N) + Offset" with fitted parameters a =  2.5066753490350954E-05, b =  7.2292352155213369E-01, and Offset =  1.6562196782144639E+01 giving RMSE = 0.2542 and R-squared = 0.99999. This combination of data and equation is extremely sensitive to initial parameter estimates. As you can see, it should interpolate with high accuracy within the data range. Since the equation is simple it will likely extrapolate well outside the data range. As I understand your description, if different computer hardware is used or if the cracking algorithm is parallelized then this solution would not match those changes.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. I have tried exp fiting but I always get "Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 800" Can you please explain how did you get your results?

Comment: I used my open source Python curve fitting web site zunzun.com to perform an equation search, it uses the Differential Evolution genetic algorithm to determine initial parameter estimates for non-linear equations like this one. Of the top candidates from the equation search results, this one seemed the most likely. I then pasted your data into the web site's fitting interface for this equation at http://zunzun.com/Equation/2/Exponential/Exponential%20With%20Offset/ and hit the Submit button.

Answer (score 2):

As this program is used for cracking, it may use some sort of brute force which leads to exponential performance time, so it's much better to find solution as

> y = a + b * c^n

for example:

> 16.38 + 2.01^n / 20000

You can try predicting `log(time)` instead of `time` in `LinearRegression`

Comment: your intuition and advice are both excellent, so I upvoted. Please see my answer to this question.